# Why rails doesn't provide date validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

You have a bunch of validators in Rails models to check numericallity, size, range, etc.

Is there a reason why there isn't any date-related validators?

PS: I know there are gems that do the job and that I can write custom validators. I'm really curious about why it's not implemented as part of the framework.

Comment: My guess is that most programmers hate dealing with dates, and no one wants to take on the responsibility of additional date functionality. Snarky, but likely the 'main' reason.